# ProgressBar won't load everywhere in the code

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-progressbar

so I've tried this all day with no success.

I have two Fragment connected, with ViewPager TabLayout,

and I've tried putting ProgressBar on each fragment, it won't show up.
I also tried putting it on the MainActivity that initiates the ViewPager for the two fragments, it also won't show.

I tried with new project and it shows. What am I doing wrong?

I've removed ProgressBar everywhere in my code, because it won't work. If you can see it for yourself here's the code.

First fragment

```
public class FilmShow extends Fragment {
    private static RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private static final String API_KEY = "2e08750083b7e21e96e915011d3f8e2d";
    private static final String TAG = FilmShow.class.getSimpleName();

public FilmShow() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getResponse getResponse = new getResponse();
    getResponse.execute();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_film_show, container, false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_tv);

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);



    return view;
}

private class getResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getList().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<Response> responseCall = apiInterface.getFilmList(API_KEY);
        responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, retrofit2.Response<Response> response) {
                List<ResultsItem> resultsItemList = response.body().getResults();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new FilmShowRecyclerAdapter(resultsItemList, getContext()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}
```

Another fragment

```
public class TvShow extends Fragment {
    private static RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private static final String API_KEY = "2e08750083b7e21e96e915011d3f8e2d";
    private static final String TAG = TvShow.class.getSimpleName();

public TvShow() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tv_show, container, false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_tv);


    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            CallInternet callInternet = new CallInternet();
            callInternet.execute();
        }
    });

    thread.run();

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


    return view;
}

private class CallInternet extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getList().create(ApiInterface.class);


        Call<Response> responseCall = apiInterface.getTvList(API_KEY);
        responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, retrofit2.Response<Response> response) {
                List<ResultsItem> resultsTv = response.body().getResults();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new TvShowRecyclerAdapter(resultsTv, getContext()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private ViewPagerAdapter adapter;


public MainActivity() {
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    // placing toolbar in place of action bar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



    /*Membuat tabLayout*/
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


    //adding fragment
    adapter.AddFragment(new TvShow(), "Tv");
    adapter.AddFragment(new FilmShow(), "Film");

    // Adapter Setrup
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_change_settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCALE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

EDIT:

Modified Another fragment to show ProgressBar on onCreateView and it works but won't stop loading

```
...............

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tv_show, container, false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_tv);
    progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    ...............
```

XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >



        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="@layout/item_tv"
            android:visibility="gone" />


        <Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />


</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT II :

```
public class TvShow extends Fragment {
    private static RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private static final String API_KEY = "2e08750083b7e21e96e915011d3f8e2d";
    private static final String TAG = TvShow.class.getSimpleName();
    private static ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        progressBar.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);


        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                CallInternet callInternet = new CallInternet();
                callInternet.execute();
            }
        });

        thread.run();
    }

    public TvShow() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
```

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.ProgressBar.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: You need to show how you are implementing and showing/hiding the progressbar otherwise it is too tough to know from above where the issue is happening.

Comment: @Azhar92 implementing inside onProgress and onPostExecute don't work

Comment: I dont understand why do you using Retrofit inside Asynctask library. Both of them have similar function

Comment: @NandaZ its required for completing the assignment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try like this

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tv_show, container, false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_tv);
    progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

// progress bar Shows first
progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getList().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<Response> responseCall = apiInterface.getFilmList(API_KEY);
        responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, retrofit2.Response<Response> response) {
                List<ResultsItem> resultsItemList = response.body().getResults();
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new FilmShowRecyclerAdapter(resultsItemList, getContext()));
progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
        progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);

            }
        });
```

This code does not required Asyntask, i just make it hide and show

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: you have to set Progressbar Widget in xml first then instance it inside fraagment

Comment: private static ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        progressBar.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);

Comment: i edited my answer, i change execution inside `onCreateView` method

Comment: Yes it's about lifecycle of fragment

Comment: `onCreateView` is called after `onCreate`, first your progressbar is hidden but suddenly it appear again when `onCreateView` has been calling (bcoz it's status is visible in xml file). That's why it still appears. I give you  advise to perform UI update inside `onCreateView`. Then instance Logic inside 'onCreate`

Comment: Alright so you call UI inside `onCreateView`, and why is `AsyncTask` won't show the progressbar inside `onPreExecute`, `onProgress`, and `onPost`? this `AsyncTask` is called inside `onCreateView`

Comment: If you perform Asyntask when your state on InBackground you can not access Main Thread. Main thead only allowed be access in postExecute, but in your case this is not suitable. Asyntask is classic sample to perform HttpRest, if you using retrofit you can do what Asynctask do. Both of them are same in functionality